# Windows Server 2008R2 - Disk Clean does not work

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, disk-cleanup, winsxs

I have a Windows 2008R2 server and my WinSXS folder is 12 GB.  I have tried to use the Disk Clean up utility and that does not cleanup the WINSXS foder.  Any ideas !!!

I have rebooted this machine several times.  Have run the Disk Cleanup utiltity as ADMIN and have the most current Windows updates.

Has anyone encountered this problem !!

Comment: Please read http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2014/05/13/how-to-clean-up-the-winsxs-directory-and-free-up-disk-space-on-windows-server-2008-r2-with-new-update.aspx

Comment: The files contained in the WinSxS are required to repair any damage to your system files, if you remove them, and in the future those system files are damaged they cannot be repaired by using DISM and SFC in the future.  The actual size of WinSxS is a great deal smaller then since that likely is just you right clicking and selecting properties on the folder.

Comment: if Windows shows "error during configuring updates" during reboot, copy the folder C:\Windows\logs\CBS to the desktop, create a zip, share the zip and post a link here.

Comment: Thank you all.  I understand  the risks but this is my test Virtual Machine so I am willing to lose it all if needed.

Comment: I've never understood why everyone seems to think that winSxS is anything but OS files, and thus something they can/should remove.

Comment: have you uploaded the logs?

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

> DISM /online /Cleanup-Image /SpSuperseded

Or you can try clean with `cleanmgr.exe`

More info [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2795190/en-us)

Comment: Thank you - I have read that article and followed all the steps ... however I the WINSXS folder does  not get cleaned up.  I will try the above command you sent and see if that works

Comment: The command isn't a Windows Server 2008R2 - ( Windows 7 ) command though so that won't work.  The author already used what is described in the article you linked to.

Comment: This is the especific versión in the article: "Windows 7 Service Pack 1 or Windows Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1"

Comment: Disk cleanup already has that feature built in to it, [this option](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jdTOC.png) does the same thing as `DISM /online /Cleanup-Image /SpSuperseded`